# Thread in Park stage, oracle.ucp.util (connection pooling)

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle

I am facing one issue where my multiple threads are in Park stage in Oracle ucp 
below is the stack trace, also if anyone having the source code for oracle.ucp.util package that would be really helpful

```
java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for <773dc402> (a java.util.concurrent.FutureTask)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(FutureTask.java:426)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:204)
at oracle.ucp.util.UCPTaskManagerImpl$3.get(UCPTaskManagerImpl.java:144)
at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalPooledConnectionImpl.isValid(UniversalPooledConnectionImpl.java:248)
at oracle.ucp.common.FailoverableUniversalPooledConnectionBase.isValid(FailoverableUniversalPooledConnectionBase.java:14)
at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalPooledConnectionImpl.isValid(UniversalPooledConnectionImpl.java:216)
at oracle.ucp.common.FailoverableUniversalPooledConnectionBase.isValid(FailoverableUniversalPooledConnectionBase.java:14)
at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.borrowConnectionAndValidate(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:178)
at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.borrowConnection(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:148)
at oracle.ucp.jdbc.JDBCConnectionPool.borrowConnection(JDBCConnectionPool.java:166)
at oracle.ucp.jdbc.oracle.OracleJDBCConnectionPool.borrowConnection(OracleJDBCConnectionPool.java:1441)
at oracle.ucp.jdbc.oracle.OracleConnectionConnectionPool.borrowConnection(OracleConnectionConnectionPool.java:82)
at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:1043)
at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:985)
at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:966)
```

Comment: http://oracle.developer-works.com/article/5227563/UCP+problem%3A+connections+time+out+but+can+still+be+used

Answer (score 0):

UCP uses 24 threads to operate. What you're observing may be just a normal operation.